# PHP & JavaScript - Confirm with values from drop down

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a form that I am populating from the database using PHP.
I would like a popup using Javascript confirming if the user would like to delete the movie.

The popup should contain the movie & release year.

Thus far, only the first value will appear in the popup...

```
    print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
    print("function confirmDelete(){");
    print("var del = document.getElementById('movie').value;\n");
    print("var status = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete: ' + del + '?');\n");
    print("return status;\n");
    print("}</script>\n");
    
    print("<h1>Delete Record</h1>");
    //Select Movies
    $query = "SELECT title release_year
              FROM movies
              ORDER BY title";
    $result = mysql_query($query) 
            or die("<h1>Error - (Movies) the query could not be executed</h1>\n");
    
    print("<form method=\"post\" action\"\">\n");
    print("<select id=\"movie\" name=\"movies\">\n");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        print("<option value=\"$row[0], $row[1]\">$row[0]</option>\n");
    print("</select>\n");
    print("<input name=\"select_delete\" type=\"submit\" 
    value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"return confirmDelete();\">\n");
    print("</form>\n");
```

Whats the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function to confirm user action

```
....
print("<input name=\"select_delete\" type=\"submit\" 
value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"confirmDelete();\">\n");
print("</form>\n");
?>

<script>
function confirmDelete()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("movie");
    var msg = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var x;
    var r=confirm("Delete" + msg + "entry?");
    if (r==true)
    {
        //OK button pressed
    }
    else
    {
        //Cancel button pressed
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Miltos,  Thanks for your reply. I still only get the first value from the option. E.g. the popup states "Delete Underworld entry?", where as I need it to say "Delete Underworld,2003 entry?".

Comment: look at your html source, is like this `<option value="movie, year">movie</option>`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = confirm('confirmation message here');
  if (x) {
    form.removeEventListener('submit');
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the 'delete function' using ajax and most of your code you can simply write like this:

```
    <?php
//code in php
?>
code in javascript
<?php
//more code in php
?>
```